# Replicate library in Pyscript

Tags: python, backend, pyscript

I'm using **Pyscript** and I want to use some **libraries** such as **replicate** and **os**

I try :

```
<py-env>
        - os    
        - replicate
</py-env>>
```

The error says :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.10/_pyodide/_base.py", line 460, in eval_code
    .run(globals, locals)
  File "/lib/python3.10/_pyodide/_base.py", line 306, in run
    coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals)
  File "<exec>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'replicate'
```

What should I do to make the OS and replicate **libraries** work? Do I have an **alternative** solution to make my task work? Does **Django** do it easily? Or it can work with **Pyscript**?

Comment: I think pyscript only works with a set (but probably growing) list of libaries, and replicate ain't on it. Check out here: https://docs.pyscript.net/tutorials/getting-started/#packages-and-modules

Comment: I was able to import them just fine

Comment: py-env has been replaced by py-config which is 'better' - https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/tutorials/py-config-fetch.html -https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/elements/py-config.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked just fine for me. AFAIK pyscript is able to work with any library that has a valid plrebuilt wheels. (I may be wrong) Also `os` comes prepackaged with pyscript:

`pyscript.html`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
<py-config>
    packages = [
      "replicate"
    ]
</py-config>
<div style="margin-right: 3rem">
    <py-repl id="my-repl" auto-generate="true"> </py-repl>
    <div id="output" class="p-4"></div>
</div>
<div id="mpl">
</div>
```

And in the browser:

`PATH_TO/pyscript1.html`

```
>>> import os, replicate
>>>
```